# Why does mdc-top-app-bar is not show correct MDC

Tags: angular, material-design

Could you tell me where I made mistake. I would like to use [mdc-top-app-bar](https://material.io/develop/web/components/top-app-bar/) but it does`t work.

My module structure: .html, .scss, .ts, .spec

header.component.html

```
<header class=" mdc-top-app-bar">
  <div class="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
    <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
      <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon--unbounded">menu</button><span class="mdc-top-app-bar__title">San Francisco, CA</span> </section>
    <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-end">
      <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__action-item--unbounded" aria-label="Download">file_download</button>
      <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__action-item--unbounded" aria-label="Print this page">print</button>
      <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__action-item--unbounded" aria-label="Bookmark this page">bookmark</button>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>
```

here is my .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MDCTopAppBar} from '@material/top-app-bar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const topAppBarElement = document.querySelector('.mdc-top-app-bar');
    const topAppBar = new MDCTopAppBar(topAppBarElement);
  }
}
```

and this is how my code look like ;)

[image]

I use this in .scss file

```
@use "@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar";
@use "@material/icon-button/mdc-icon-button";
```

but I get error

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
   ╷
23 │ @use "@material/elevation/mixins" as elevation-mixins;
   │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  node_modules\@material\top-app-bar\mdc-top-app-bar.scss 23:1  @use
  C:\Users\\CarApp\car-shareing-app\src\app\modules\home\components\car-dictionary\car-dictionary-list\car-dictionary-list.component.scss 1:1                                                     root stylesheet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. I found solution there is a problem with mdc-top-app-bar and google does not fixed :( [File to import not found or unreadable](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1416) I will choose another tool for navigation